# Audio cannot be played with speed change through Telegram API

Tags: api, telegram, telegram-bot, playback, telebot

I uploaded a MP3 file to a Telegram channel through Python telebot library automation but the audio cannot be played with speed change. What have I done wrong?

Tried to send MP3 as 'document' as well as 'audio' but still not getting it fixed...

Comment: Did you figure out a solution? I noticed the same thing